# Create several WCF services or 1 service with several methods?

Tags: wcf, methods

I want to create an application that will need several calls to webservices to get data for persons, companies, etc. What is the best practice for that:

Create one SVC file / WCF webservices with several methods

or

Create for each entity (person_webservice.svc / company_webservice.svc) a webservice file with only the methode related to that entity?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to manage the visibility, security, transport or other configurable details for each WCF separately then go for multiple WCF's, if all the services are related, share same server, do not need isolation then managing multiple services will get complicated over time and could end up with duplicate code easily.

WebAPI is the modern version of your split WCF idea, each API controller defines the actions specific to a single entity but all belong to the same 'endpoint' or base url.

Comment: Thanks Paul this answer really helped dive into more topics like WebApi!